# My createTokenPair function isnt working when I call it from my frontend please help

Tags: uniswap, evm, react, defi, uniswapv2

**Hello, I`ve forked Uniswap V2 perfectly fine on the backend and now I want to connect it to my frontend. I have built a basic webpage and I am now doing the frontend. When calling the createPair function, my frontend isnt responsing and showing the following error in the console.log:**

```
POST https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/XXX 400
(anonym) @ browser-geturl.ts:35
(anonym) @ browser-geturl.ts:1
__awaiter @ browser-geturl.ts:1
getUrl @ browser-geturl.ts:9
(anonym) @ index.ts:253
(anonym) @ index.ts:1
__awaiter @ index.ts:1
(anonym) @ index.ts:247
_fetchData @ index.ts:363
fetchJson @ index.ts:410
send @ json-rpc-provider.ts:523
(anonym) @ json-rpc-provider.ts:255
Promise.then (asynchron)
sendUncheckedTransaction @ json-rpc-provider.ts:243
(anonym) @ json-rpc-provider.ts:281
fulfilled @ json-rpc-provider.ts:1
Promise.then (asynchron)
step @ json-rpc-provider.ts:1
(anonym) @ json-rpc-provider.ts:1
__awaiter @ json-rpc-provider.ts:1
sendTransaction @ json-rpc-provider.ts:276
createPair @ uniswap.js:28
await in createPair (asynchron)
handleCreatePair @ Pool.js:17
await in handleCreatePair (asynchron)
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonym) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
uniswap.js:33 
        
       Error creating pair: Error: bad response (status=400, headers={"content-length":"179","content-type":"application/json"}, body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":47,\"error\":{\"code\":-32600,\"message\":\"Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis\"}}", requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendTransaction\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x1eb892\",\"from\":\"0xf450b38cccfdcfad2f98f7e4bb533151a2fb00e9\",\"to\":\"0x28fe679719e740d15fc60325416bb43eac50cd15\",\"data\":\"0xc9c65396000000000000000000000000a14cb03507a29ce3167ec83998050ae9237ad16a000000000000000000000000b4fbf271143f4fbf7b91a5ded31805e42b2208d6\"}],\"id\":47,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/XXX", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at index.ts:308:1
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
createPair @ uniswap.js:33
await in createPair (asynchron)
handleCreatePair @ Pool.js:17
await in handleCreatePair (asynchron)
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonym) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
Pool.js:18 Pair created at address: undefined
```

**This is the code to my Pool.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { init, createPair, addLiquidity } from './uniswap';
import './Pool.css';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

const providerUrl = 'https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/XXX';

function Pool({ account }) {
  const [tokenA, setTokenA] = useState('');
  const [tokenB, setTokenB] = useState('');
  const [amountADesired, setAmountADesired] = useState('');
  const [amountBDesired, setAmountBDesired] = useState('');

  const handleCreatePair = async () => {
    await init(providerUrl, account);
    const pairAddress = await createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
    console.log('Pair created at address:', pairAddress);
  };

  const handleAddLiquidity = async () => {
    const amountADesiredBN = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountADesired, 18); 
    const amountBDesiredBN = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountBDesired, 18); 
    const amountAMin = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountADesired, 18); 
    const amountBMin = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountBDesired, 18); 
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 20 * 60; // 20 minutes from now
    const to = account; 
    await addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesiredBN, amountBDesiredBN, amountAMin, amountBMin, to, deadline);
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="Pool">
      <h1>Create Token Pair</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={tokenA}
        onChange={(e) => setTokenA(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Token A address"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={tokenB}
        onChange={(e) => setTokenB(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Token B address"
      />
      <button onClick={handleCreatePair}>Create Pair</button>
      <h1>Add Liquidity</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={amountADesired}
        onChange={(e) => setAmountADesired(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Amount A desired"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={amountBDesired}
        onChange={(e) => setAmountBDesired(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Amount B desired"
      />
      <button onClick={handleAddLiquidity}>Add Liquidity</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pool;
```

**and this is the uniswap.js file with the logic behind it:**

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import UniswapV2FactoryABI from '../abis/Factory.sol/UniswapV2Factory.json';
import UniswapRouter02ABI from '../abis/Router.sol/UniswapV2Router02.json';

const UniswapV2FactoryAddress = '0x28fE679719e740D15FC60325416bB43eAc50cD15';
const UniswapRouter02Address = '0xeAEdaF63CbC1d00cB6C14B5c4DE161d68b7C63A0';

let provider, signer, factoryContract, routerContract;

async function init(providerUrl, account) {
  provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(providerUrl);
  signer = provider.getSigner(account);

  // Add the console.log statements here to log the ABIs
  console.log('Factory ABI:', UniswapV2FactoryABI);
  console.log('Router ABI:', UniswapRouter02ABI);

  factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(UniswapV2FactoryAddress, UniswapV2FactoryABI.abi, signer);
  routerContract = new ethers.Contract(UniswapRouter02Address, UniswapRouter02ABI.abi, signer);
}




async function createPair(tokenA, tokenB) {
  try {
    const createPairTx = await factoryContract.populateTransaction.createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
    const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(createPairTx);
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    const event = receipt.events.find((e) => e.event === 'PairCreated');
    return event.args.pair;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating pair:', error);
  }
}


async function addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin, to, deadline) {
  try {
    const tx = await routerContract.addLiquidity(
      tokenA,
      tokenB,
      amountADesired,
      amountBDesired,
      amountAMin,
      amountBMin,
      to,
      deadline
    );
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    return receipt;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding liquidity:', error);
  }
}

export { init, createPair, addLiquidity };
```

I would be very gratefulif someone can help me and even send a token tip if possible. Thanks a lot. I cant find anything online of fixing this. I have of course censored the alchemyaddress